# Multiple errors when running fetch request for an API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

I am trying to get data from this API:
https://transfermarkt-api.vercel.app/players/122153/transfers

When running a fetch request I get some errors. (When I paste the URL in my browser it displays data)

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
fetch('https://transfermarkt-api.vercel.app/players/122153/transfers', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'accept': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log(data); // Handle the response data here
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('Error:', error); // Handle errors here
});
```

Errors displayed in console:

[image: errors:]

I highly appreciate any help

I have looked at some questions that all seemed a little too complex for what I am trying to do, so I thought I would ask.

Comment: Im not sure if all of that is necessary... I tried a different api and it works fine in my file. could the problem be with this api?

Comment: Yes, all of this **is** necessary if you want do make cross origin requests. That "other api"  probably supports them already ...